# C++11 parameters pack overload

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a function:

```
template <typename A>
Foo createFoo() {

    std::initializer_list<std::size_t> list = { Object<A>::getIndex() } );
    return Foo(list);
}
```

It is invoked like:

```
Foo foo = createFoo<Bar>();
```

It works correct, returning me an object of class `Foo`.

Is it possible to write a specialized function in case there're more than one parameter argument, something like this?

```
template <typename A1, typename A2, typename...Ax>
Foo createFoo() {

    std::initializer_list<std::size_t> list = { Object<A1>::getIndex(), Object<A2>::getIndex()... } );
    return Foo(list);
}
```

So that I invoke it this way:

```
Foo foo = createFoo<Bar, Fred, Wilma>();
```

It gives me an error:

> error: expansion pattern ‘Object::getIndex()’ contains no argument packs

and points to the "..." part of the code.

I don't want to have a single function declared as

```
template <typename ...A>
Foo createFoo() {

    std::initializer_list<std::size_t> list = { Object<A>::getIndex() } );
    return Foo(list);
}
```

because, let's suppose the `Foo` class has optimized logics in case there's only one `std::size_t` item in the initializer_list and I want to utilize that in my API.

I use GCC version 4.8.4 with `-std=c++11` option

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
std::initializer_list<std::size_t> list = { Object<A1>::getIndex(), Object<A2>::getIndex()... } );
```

when you put `...` after a function call, it looks for parameter packs inside of that to expand, but `A2` isn't a parameter pack, `Ax` is.

Why even have the A1 and A2?

```
template <typename...Ax>
Foo createFoo() {
```

Then you can just say `Object<Ax>::getIndex()...`

Or if you must enforce a certain number of parameters, then:

```
std::initializer_list<std::size_t> list = { Object<A1>::getIndex(),Object<A2>::getIndex(), Object<Ax>::getIndex()... } );
```

The `...` expansion accepts an empty parameter pack, so this will work for 2 or more types.

Comment: because I want to maintain two different `createFoo` functions, overloaded by amount of parameters, as I tried to express in my question.

Comment: yeah, all that matters is the one with the ... after it contains a type parameter pack, not a single type.

Comment: Just remember the ... in the code has to match up with the ... in the template