# Auto-deduce method's return type

Tags: c++, c++11, type-inference

I have the following functions:

```
//method takes 2 or more template parameters    
template <class A1, class A2, class ...Ax>
Value<FooMany> getValue() {

    //note, FooAll's ctor takes std::string and std::initializer_list<std::size_t>

    FooAll<Item> hairyStructure("abc", { Foo<A1>::getIndex(), Foo<A2>::getIndex(), Foo<Ax>::getIndex() ... } );
    return Value<FooMany>(someData, hairyStructure);
}

//method takes only 1 template parameter
template <class A>
Value<FooSingle> getValue() {

    //note, FooOne's ctor takes std::string and std::size_t

    FooOne<Item> hairyStructure("abc", Foo<A>::getIndex() );
    return Value<FooSingle>(someData, hairyStructure);
}
```

.

Obviously, the types of these functions are different.

I wonder, is it possible to squash these two into the single method, which, utilizing the C++11 features (decltype, I suppose),
would auto-deduce the return type?

So, basically, it should return `Value<FooSingle>` if `getValue` is invoked as

`GetValue<A>();`

and it should return `Value<FooMany>` if it is invoked for example as

`GetValue<A, B>();`

or

`GetValue<A, B, C>();`

I am not sure if my terminology is correct regarding "method takes 2 or more template parameters". Please correct me if it is wrong.

If it helps, my question continues the previous topic: [C++11 parameters pack overload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35403116/c11-parameters-pack-overload)

Thank you.

Comment: The type is one thing, but how would you write the `return`-statement in the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <type_traits>

template <class A1, class... Ax>
auto getValue()
    -> Value<typename std::conditional<sizeof...(Ax) == 0
                                     , FooSingle, FooMany>::type>
{
    typename std::conditional<sizeof...(Ax) == 0
                            , FooOne<Item> 
                            , FooAll<Item>>::type
              hairyStructure("abc", { Foo<A1>::getIndex(), Foo<Ax>::getIndex()... } );
    return Value<typename std::conditional<sizeof...(Ax) == 0
                                         , FooSingle, FooMany>::type>(hairyStructure);
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c30306876c5dbca2)

Comment: I don't understand why there's explicit `FooAll<Item>. it should variate between FooAll and FooOne, am I right?

Comment: I really don't find this more readable than just using two overloads.